# Correcting the following sentence: The passengers complain that the local trains often runs on a regular schedule

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, verbs, word-usage

My ESL book has a lot of typos and does not have the answers for many practice questions. How should I correct the following sentence?

"The passengers complain that the local trains often runs on a regular schedule."

My one guess is "the local trains often run late on a regular schedule."

Thank you.

Comment: There is an ESL forum here https://ell.stackexchange.com/ that you should use for beginner level comprehension.  To give you a hint:  Do you really think that people would complain about trains coming on a ~regular~ schedule ?  Maybe there is another very similar but opposite word that would fit better ?

Comment: You're correct that *trains* ***run***.  So you're on the right track. ;)

Comment: I think i just failed ESL for not noting what @RaceYouAnytime points out

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why anyone would complain about trains running on a regular schedule, but we'll let that pass for the moment.

The problem that I see is the disconnect between the subject of the complaint and the verb.  "Trains" is plural so it should be "run" (unless there is only one train, in which case it should be *the local train often runs*.)

So I would say the (grammatically) correct sentence is either:

> The passengers complain that the local trains often run on a regular schedule.

or

> The passengers complain that the local train often runs on a regular schedule.

Logically, however, it's more likely that *the passengers complain that the local trains **do not** run on a regular schedule*.  (Except in the US where we're used to it.)

Comment: It's hard to know when to show up when something runs ~ on an irregular ~ schedule.

Comment: It is, but maybe they like to have some uncertainty in their lives to spice things up a bit?  Around here, we just allow for extra time.